# How to remove rich text field tags in xslt <span>, <p> etc

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I have value coming as

```
<sf:pitch>&lt;p>&lt;span style="color: rgb(68, 68, 68);">https://PPsdfgndgnlksdnflksklenrgkdngldsfklsndfg.com.au&lt;/span>&lt;/p> </sf:pitch>
```

and I want the output to be like and remove every "p", "span" and non text stripped from the SF:pitch value.

```
https://PPsdfgndgnlksdnflksklenrgkdngldsfklsndfg.com.au
```

I have put the code to remove `<p>` but I want a generic code to remove any tag from the value.

Code which I used to remove `<p>` is

```
<xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after(*:Envelope/*:Body/*:retrieveResponse/*:result/*:pitch, '&lt;p&gt;'), '&lt;/p&gt;')" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
```

Comment: Your question is likely incomplete. Do you want every "p", "span" and "sf:pitch" stripped?

Comment: Please post a [mcve], not snippets of code taken out of context

Comment: I want to remove all the html tags from the text.

Answer (score 1):

You say:

> I want a generic code to remove any tag from the value

But there aren't any "tags" in the value of  `sf:pitch`; it's all a single string containing some escaped markup. Unless you convert the string to XML first (using either XSLT 3.0 or a separate transformation that disables the escaping) and process it as such, you must process it using string manipulation - which is difficult and error-prone.

Perhaps you could do something like:

```
<xsl:value-of select="replace($string, '.*&gt;([^&lt;]+)&lt;.*', '$1')" />
```

where `$string` is the `sf:pitch` element in your example.

But overall, this is not a good approach - see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/17153010) why.

Comment: if you see the sf:pitch value contains span and p tags.

Comment: @NiteshBagri No, I do NOT see that. As I said, it contains **escaped** markup. There are no tags in escaped markup, it's just a meaningless string.

Comment: this meaningless string is creating issues when I am passing them in API calls. the text inside sf:pitch is " &lt;p>&lt;span style="color: rgb(68, 68, 68);">https://PPsdfgndgnlksdnflksklenrgkdngldsfklsndfg.com.au&lt;/span>&lt;/p>" and I want to remove everything and want output as "https://PPsdfgndgnlksdnflksklenrgkdngldsfklsndfg.com.au"

Comment: your code works Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the `fn:parse-xml()` function, or a similar extension function, then use `string(parse-xml(text()))`. That's assuming the content is well-formed XML. Alternatives are `parse-xml-fragment()` or `parse-html()`

Answer (score -1):

```
<xsl:template match="sf:pitch">
  <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
</xsl:template>
```

But you have not stated whether it is every sf:pitch or any other possible variations.

Comment: This wouldn't have worked even with unescaped markup. The `sf:pitch` element does not have any child text nodes.